# StackExchange sites freeze and text lags while I am typing a question using Chrome

Tags: bug, google-chrome

I have had this happening to me for quite some time. I see the caret in the text area just fine but as soon as I started typing, the page freezes and the text appears letter by letter, one letter every 5 seconds or so; when I stop typing, it continues to stay frozen until the last letter I typed appears, thats when the caret starts to blink at the end just fine. It has been happening for quite some time so I decided to report it today. I have to type up my questions in a separate text editor and copy-paste them here. Am I the only one experiencing it?

Browser: Google Chrome with Auto-Update
ISP: Comcast, 100+ Mbps
Location: Florida, USA

Extensions installed:
Cisco WebEx Extension
Currently
Google Docs
Google Docs Offline
Google Hangouts
Google Sheets
Google Slides
One Click Google Hangout
Postman

I have tried disabling ALL the extensions above. No help.

Comment: What's your browser?  What's your internet connection speed?  Where are you geolocated (rough location is fine; this is important since users from certain parts of the world have had spotty connections to the site)?  What browser plugins do you have enabled?  Do you have a firewall armed?

Comment: @Makoto question updated.

Comment: Chrome... next..  :)

Comment: @MartinJames I refuse to respond to your counter-productive and ignorant comment.

Comment: You may well see it as counter-productive, (though it does not really suggest anything other than I'm moving on).  'Ignorant', though, does not stand. I have had experiences with Chrome, and they've been universally bad:(

Comment: Any add-ons/extensions/plug-ins installed? What happens when you disable them? Any errors in the developer console? What are they?